# Using busybox telnet, teminal emulator and ubuntu

Tags: linux, terminal, busybox

I want to conrol android command line (Jackpal's Terminal) using busybox telnet. With Spartacus Rex' Terminal ide telnet works but cant get out of 'application's context.' So I want to use Jackpal's since I have superuser privileges(i think i do :) ) But whenever I try to connect with telnet (tried on both) I get connection refused error. Any thoughts?